# How to count the number of entries in the list when requesting Select?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I apologize for the possible incorrectness in the presentation, I use a translator. Let's say there is a users table in which there is an id field. And there is a list that lists the id numbers and some of them are repeated. My query

```
select id, count(*)
from users
where id in (3, 10, 10, 10)
group by id;
```

returns the following 3 - 1, 10 - 1. And I would like to get 3 - 1, 10 - 3, and so on. Is it possible to get it somehow?
UPD.
The data in the list (3, 10, 10, 10) is just an example, the exact number of digits is not known because they are returned from another question.

Comment: okay, I just didn't have enough knowledge, but now I'm sorted out. If any newbie is faced with the same problem, it is necessary to give the list a name using the AS, and then you can easily use it in your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a `join`.  You can put the values in a derived table for this:

```
select id, count(*)
from users u join
     (select 3 as id union all
      select 10 as id union all
      select 10 as id union all
      select 10 as id union all
     ) i
     using(id)
group by id;
```

Comment: okay, but if this list is created by another nested select, and I don't know exactly what values there will be. is there a solution for this situation?

Comment: @GeorgyPlekhanov . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with more detail.  This answers the question that you asked here.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I changed the wording of the question. I think what you showed will also come in handy someday.